# Sharing state in camel?

Tags: apache-camel

It appears I am running into issues sharing information between routes.

What is the camel pattern for passing around information ?

I looked at exchange properties but that does not stick around between routes I think...

eg:

one file has one has some configutations 
i have a route to read this file
and several other routes that will act on based on the configs,

how do I accomplish this ?

I thought of puttin the values in a singleton bean, but that seems kind of ugly...

Comment: Exchange properties and indeed sometimes headers do stick between routes. That's a common pattern. You need to show  your code to be more of a help.

Comment: Is there some typical rule when a new exchange is created ? I know aggregator does that - learned the hard way

Comment: Aggregator can use properties from previous exchange depending on your Camel version. I would say the exception is that new exchanges are created. An exchange lives as long as the "transaction" is in flight.

Answer (score 0):

Exchange properties are preserved across routes inside camel (but there are some limitations and special cases when using splitter/aggregator etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Assign ID's to all sub routes which will act on based on the config. Then get the suitable Route or RouteDefinition from camel context and check whether you can advice or share information to the route according.

```
ModelCamelContext modelContext;
modelContext.getRouteDefinition(String routeId) or modelContext.getRoute(String routeId)
```